# Wrong output dimension with tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to predict pokemon's characteristics by their images.
I have a pandas dataframe with their characteristics and `path` column, which contains strings with paths to images.
I used one-hot-encoding to categorical variables. I want to create a network with mixed (categorical and continuous) output variables.
I made such generators:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range = 40,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = .2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    fill_mode = 'nearest',
    validation_split = 0.1
)
 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df,
    x_col = 'path',
    y_col = ['height_m', 'weight_kg', 'hp', 'attack', 'defense',
             'sp_attack', 'sp_defense', 'speed', 
             '1__Bug', '1__Dark', '1__Dragon', '1__Electric',
             '1__Fairy', '1__Fighting', '1__Fire', '1__Flying', '1__Ghost', 
             '1__Grass', '1__Ground', '1__Ice', '1__Normal', '1__Poison',
             '1__Psychic', '1__Rock', '1__Steel', '1__Water', '2__Bug',
             '2__Dark', '2__Dragon', '2__Electric', '2__Fairy', '2__Fighting',
             '2__Fire', '2__Flying', '2__Ghost', '2__Grass', '2__Ground',
             '2__Ice', '2__Normal', '2__Poison', '2__Psychic', '2__Rock', 
             '2__Steel', '2__Water', 'status__Legendary', 'status__Mythical',
             'status__Normal', 'status__Sub Legendary'],
    target_size=(120, 120),
    color_mode = 'rgba',
    class_mode = 'raw',
    batch_size = 32,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 1,
    subset = 'training'
)
 
test_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df,
    x_col = 'path',
    y_col = ['height_m', 'weight_kg', 'hp', 'attack', 'defense',
             'sp_attack', 'sp_defense', 'speed', 
             '1__Bug', '1__Dark', '1__Dragon', '1__Electric',
             '1__Fairy', '1__Fighting', '1__Fire', '1__Flying', '1__Ghost', 
             '1__Grass', '1__Ground', '1__Ice', '1__Normal', '1__Poison',
             '1__Psychic', '1__Rock', '1__Steel', '1__Water', '2__Bug',
             '2__Dark', '2__Dragon', '2__Electric', '2__Fairy', '2__Fighting',
             '2__Fire', '2__Flying', '2__Ghost', '2__Grass', '2__Ground',
             '2__Ice', '2__Normal', '2__Poison', '2__Psychic', '2__Rock', 
             '2__Steel', '2__Water', 'status__Legendary', 'status__Mythical',
             'status__Normal', 'status__Sub Legendary'],
    target_size=(120, 120),
    color_mode = 'rgba',
    class_mode = 'raw',
    batch_size = 4,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 1,
    subset = 'validation'
)
 
 
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
 
class SplitedGenerator(Sequence):
  def __init__(self, generator, batchsize, indecies):
    self.generator = generator
    self.batchsize = batchsize
    self.indecies = indecies
  def __len__(self):
    return self.indecies // self.batchsize
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    X, y = self.generator.next()
    return X, {'height_m':y[:,0], 'weight_kg':y[:,1], 'hp':y[:,2], 'attack':y[:,3], 'defense':y[:,4],
             'sp_attack':y[:,5], 'sp_defense':y[:,6], 'speed':y[:,7], 'type_1':y[:,8:26], 'type_2':y[:,26:-4],
             'status':y[:,-4:]}
```

The reason why I made last of them - to split outputs in dictionary with 8 continious charasteristics, 18 booleans for one-hot-encoded "Type 1", same "Type 2" and 4 booleans for "status".

My model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Input, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
 
input_layer = Input(shape=(120, 120, 4), name='input')
layer = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), activation='relu')(input_layer)
layer = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(layer)
layer = Conv2D(128, (7, 7), activation='relu')(layer)
layer = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(layer)
layer = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu')(layer)
layer = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(layer)
#layer = Conv2D(512, (7, 7), activation='relu')(layer)
#layer = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(layer)
layer = Dropout(0.2)(layer)
layer = Flatten()(layer)
layer = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(layer)
output_1 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='height_m')(layer)
output_2 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='weight_kg')(layer)
output_3 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='hp')(layer)
output_4 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='attack')(layer)
output_5 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='defense')(layer)
output_6 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='sp_attack')(layer)
output_7 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='sp_defense')(layer)
output_8 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='speed')(layer)
output_9 = Dense(18, activation='softmax', name='type_1')(layer)
output_10 = Dense(18, activation='softmax', name='type_2')(layer)
output_11 = Dense(4, activation='softmax', name='status')(layer)
 
model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[output_1, output_2, output_3,
                                             output_4, output_5, output_6,
                                             output_7, output_8, output_9,
                                             output_10, output_11])
 
 
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=['mse', 'mse', 'mse', 'mse', 'mse', 'mse', 'mse', 'mse', 
          'categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy']
)
```

This model have a bunch of outputs, I train it with:

```
history = model.fit_generator(SplitedGenerator(train_generator, 32, len(df.index)), epochs=10)
```

But when I try to do:

```
X, y = test_generator.next()
print(model.predict(X)[0])
```

It prints array with only 4 elements. It does not print any error or warning(except about deprecated fit_generator method). Where is my mistake? Why does it predict only 4 variables instead of 44?

Comment: its not 4 variables, 4 is your batch size.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy oh, it looks like I see now...It do not put predictions for the first image to first element. The structure looks like this: predicted height for 4 images, predicted weight for 4 images etc.